# Is it possible to decline egit commit when files contain errors

Tags: java, eclipse, commit, egit, jgit

in CVS it was possible to configure Eclipse to allow, deny or prompt if files contained errors or warnings and a commit happened.

Is there currently anything like this in EGit already? Is there a possible workaround until this is available in EGit?

I would like to be forced automatically that I solve compile errors before commit / push. Yes, I can consider git hooks that solve this problem, but since JGit (afaik) doesn't call hooks this doesn't really help.

It would be enough to ensure this behavior for Java files. But since Eclipse supports errors for nearly all types of files I think it doesn't really matter which type of files I have.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should see that the files have an error via decoration before committing via both the Commit dialog and the Git Staging view.

Prompting when there are warnings/errors could be added as a new feature to EGit, see [bug 373067](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=373067).

Comment: Yep. I'm already thinking about which weekend I could use to try to implement it in EGit. I know that I can watch the errors manually - but that's not what I would like. Cause I want to do automatically what is possible doing automatically ;-)

Comment: There is already a feature request: https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=373067
But my question is, how can I solve this problem now by myself..

Comment: Thanks, updated answer. To solve the problem by yourself, you could consider contributing the feature to EGit, see bug report for pointers.